# curly brackets expression behaves differently for loop and while

Tags: rust

In the following snippet, `break counter * 2` ending with `;` or not, would not affect it returns value 20. It is different from what I find in rust online book, which says expression must not end with `;`.

What is more unbelievable is, `{}` is said to be an expression, it is true in `loop` but not `while`, so the last `println!` throws an error like `cannot format` which I guess counter is an empty tuple. But I think counter should be integer 0.

```
fn loop_flow() {
    let mut counter = 0;
    let a = loop {
        counter += 1;
        if counter == 10 {
            break counter * 2
        }
    }; 
    println!("value a is {}", a);

    let counter = while counter != 0 {
        counter -= 1;
        counter
    }

    println!("counter: {} should be 0", counter);

}
```

Comment: Where is the while version for comparison?

Comment: First question has an answer here: [Break with or without semicolon](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65024479/why-does-break-not-need-a-semicolon-when-ending-a-loop).

Comment: [`for` and `while` only return `()`](https://github.com/rust-lang/rfcs/issues/1767#issuecomment-292678002).

Comment: @NomadMaker there isn't such in tutorial. When I saw `let a = loop` I wonder `let a = while`

Comment: @Mihir Thanks! I guess the reasons are under aggreement. But this inconsistent performance confuses a new learner, like me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> In the following snippet, break counter * 2 ending with ; or not, would not affect it returns value 20. It is different from what I find in rust online book, which says expression must not end with ;.

Like `return`, `break` is more of a statement than an expression: [it never actually returns anything itself](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bottom_type) instead it jumps out of a body (function and loop respectively).

> What is more unbelievable is, {} is said to be an expression, it is true in loop but not while, so the last println! throws an error like cannot format which I guess counter is an empty tuple. But I think counter should be integer 0.

A lone block:

```
let a = { 1 };
```

is an expression.

In a `loop` or `while`, however, `{}` is a "body" and the rules are completely different. While a `while` is an expression, it doesn't and can't return anything useful since the body could execute 0 times. Thus the result of a `while` is always `()`.

In fact, not only does rustc complain that it can not format `()`, it first complains that the "result" of a `while` body must be `()`:

```
error[E0308]: mismatched types
  --> src/lib.rs:13:9
   |
11 |       let counter = while counter != 0 {
   |  ___________________-
12 | |         counter -= 1;
13 | |         counter
   | |         ^^^^^^^ expected `()`, found integer
14 | |     };
   | |     -- help: consider using a semicolon here
   | |_____|
   |       expected this to be `()`
```

[This is documented](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/keyword.while.html):

> Like the `for` expression, we can use `break` and `continue`. A `while` expression cannot break with a value and always evaluates to `()` unlike `loop`.

Comment: The reason why while return () is acceptable.